# Using java8 how can we sort elements starting from the second element to till last?

Tags: java-8

Using java8 how can we sort elements starting from the second element to till last?

```
  list.stream().filter(student -> student.getAge()!=15).sorted(Comparator.comparing(student->student.getAge())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The final sorted list should contain all the elements including first one.

I have tried above code snippet:

Here i dont want to touch first element.The above code is sorting from 2nd element to till last element.the problem is i am not getting first element(age =15) in output.

If i dont apply filter it will sort all the elements and i will loose first element, which should not happen.

Please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
 List<Student> result = Stream.concat(
            list.stream().findFirst().map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()),
            list.stream().skip(1).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Excelent answer! thanks for sharing, I was trying to do it in a easy way, plus one

Comment: It is not safe to call `get` on `Optional`. Try to replace  `Stream.of(list.stream().findFirst().get())` with `list.stream().findFirst().map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)`

Comment: nice trick with Optional.stream, but it will work only since java9 :)

Comment: yes, and `Stream::empty` is a supplier of empty streams

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk my point was that you don't need a `Supplier` here (sorry for not making sense immediately). `Stream.empty` is cheap creation, usually a Supplier is used when the object construction would have some weight...

Comment: good point. For me it is a matter of taste, in this specific example I don't have a preference

Comment: `list.stream().findFirst().map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty())`, seriously? What about `list.stream().limit(1)`? I mean, you are using `.skip(1)` in the counterpart… Anyway, [that doesn’t look like a good Stream API task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495113/2711488).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`List.subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method to skip the first element of the list:

```
List<Student> result = list.isEmpty() ? new ArrayList<>() : // or just list
    Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(list.get(0)),
        list.subList(1, list.size()).stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `subList` is the correct pointer, if you go the next step and forget about the Stream API for this specific task…

Comment: @Holger you are absolutely correct. Your answer is the best one by far...

Answer (score 2):

Rethink whether the Stream API is the best choice here:

```
List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
result.subList(1, list.size()).sort(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge));
```

Note that if the source list is mutable and you don’t need the original list order, you can do the operation directly on the source list using only the second line of above code snippet.

Comment: oh damn, so much better... :(

Comment: @Eugene I was quite near... And Holger, congrats on the 100k

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can filter the first element after procesing the whole list:

```
Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(list.stream().findFirst().get()),
        list.stream().skip(1).sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).skip(1);
```